# how to check null from JCR value in Adobe CQ5..?

Tags: jsp, adobe, components, aem, jcr

Hi all i'm new Adobe CQ5, i'm getting values from JCR in Adobe CQ5 component, value is rendering fine but now want to check null, i'm doing like this:

```
  <% if(<%= properties.get("videoImage") %> != null)
     {
       <img src=<%= properties.get("videoImage") %> />
     }
  %>
```

but it generate an error, can any one suggest what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: how do you intialise the `properties` object ?

Comment: i declare this name as property in CRX, i'm getting it fine but getting issue at the time of checking null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better way to achieve it.

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("videoImage", properties.get("videoImage", ""));%>
    <c:if test="${not empty videoImage}">
        <img src="${videoImage}" />
    </c:if>
```

Ideally set all of your variables to session, request, page context attributes at one place in top and you may use it throughout component jsp, alternatively much cleaner approach will be to declare all of them in a jsp and include them using `<cq:include script"path/to/jsp">`

Comment: `properties` object is already set as the page attribute, so the first line is redundant if we use `properties.videoImage` in JSTL directives. See my response for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Use [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm):

```
<c:if test="${not empty properties.videoImage}">
    <img src="${properties.videoImage}" />
</c:if>
```

or switch from JSP to [Sightly](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly.html#test) (a recommended option):

```
<img data-sly-test="${properties.videoImage}" src="${properties.videoImage}" />
```

Comment: can you suggest me how to check same null condition for Anchor href

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is you are not terminating the `scriptlets` properly ,

```
  <% if(properties.get("videoImage") != null)
     { %> 
       <img src=<%= properties.get("videoImage") %> />
   <%}
  %>
```

Dont mix `html` and `Java` codes in your jsp.

Read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)